# Prevent users from copying ClickOnce application

Tags: security, clickonce, windows

I have a ClickOnce app in .NET 4.0;
How can i prevent users from copying the whole installation directory from one machine to another?

I don't need a solution that can't be hacked(if there's one), but i need one to stop everyday users from doing this;

---

I already tried the following:

- Store the MAC address when the app is installed, and try to match it every time the app starts - this didn't work because users might use wired or wireless connections;
- Match the HDD serial key - it doesn't work for WinXP;

---

Some extra info that might help:
I'm keeping track of my customers in a DB: when a customer requests the product, i add a new record ; When they run the app for the first time, the app asks for the ProdId, and changes the status so they can't install it again using the same ProdId;

Comment: I'd argue with the tombstone already set for WinXP that if the HDD trick doesn't work there... Who cares, don't waste time chasing those users. Just make sure you are forgiving to your ***paying customers*** if they need to reinstall after getting a new/additional HDD due to a disk error, virus, corruption, ransom ware encryption,etc. I'd be very upset if for some reason I bought the software, had a computer issue and had to buy a new disk drive or new PC and then was told my purchased software was no longer valid.

Comment: @scunliffe-that's the problem, there are specific target-users and most of them are using WinXP. Regarding the license, they can email me and i'll renew their license;

Comment: @scunliffe-based on your idea,i might work on something: use the HDD serial key, and if it's not available(winXP), use the MAC; Thanks! I'll let you know the progress.